# If I have that $X \sim \chi^2_{1}$ and $Y \sim \chi^2_{2}$ are independent, how can I show that $4XY \sim Y^2$?

Tags: probability, statistics

If I have that $X \sim \chi^2_{1}$ and $Y \sim \chi^2_{2}$ are independent, how can I show that $4XY \sim Y^2$? Here, I have that $X \sim \chi^2_{1}$ means that $X$ is a chi-square random variable with 1 degree of freedom and that $Y \sim \chi^2_{2}$ has two degrees of freedom. Is there a way to do this without integration and more by representation? I have thought about moment generating functions, or taking the expectations, but am not sure how to do it. I've also thought about taking logs of both sides to induce additivity. Finally, the $4XY$ looks suspiciously set up as I know that $(X+Y)^2 - (X-Y)^2 = 4XY$. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Note that $Y\sim \exp(1/2)$ - that should make change of variable formula to compare densities of both sides painless.

Comment: Thanks, I am not really seeing how the change of variable works here, do you mind if you elaborate? thanks

Comment: You know $X$ and $Y$, so you can find pdf of $U=XY$ (choose $V=X$ or $V=Y$ and then integrate it out). pdf of $Y^2$ is even easier - single-variable change. Since all pdfs are of the type $\exp$ to a polynomial of degree at most $2$, it should be straightforward.

Comment: Here is less painful way. $P(Y^2>t)=\exp(-\frac 1 2\sqrt t)$. $P(4XY>t)=E(\exp(-\frac t {8X}))=\frac 2{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2/2-t/8x^2}$. Complete the square with a minus sign to cancel the other side and you are left with one integral to be done by substitution.

Comment: what is $\sim Y^2$?